# Spark SFTP Connector Library - Spark SFTP connection failing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-sftp

Trying to connect to file in another cluster through SFTP and nothing worked.

> Current spark version is : '2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91 .
>
> scala :2.11.8'

.

Below is the data frame :

```
val df_file_feed =spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").option("host","1-1111").option("username","user").option("password","pasword").option("fileType","csv").load("/home/folder/Path_02.csv")


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.springml.spark.sftp.
```

also tried  these  jars . `spark-sftp_2.10-1.0.2.jar                                                               spark-sftp_2.11-1.1.0.jar ,spark-sftp_2.11-1.1.4.jar`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the spark-shell you have to try like this...

```
bin/spark-shell --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.3
```

have a look at [Spark SFTP Connector Library](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp) which states that

Linking
You can link against this library in your program at the following ways:

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.springml</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sftp_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

SBT Dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "com.springml" % "spark-sftp_2.11" % "1.1.3"
```

Comment: I tried adding these dependencies with version 1.1.3,1.14,1.1.1,1.1.0.Nothing is working , it still says  Failed to find data source: com.springml.spark.sftp. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: are you running from program or spark-shell ?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.springml</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sftp_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  These are dependencies i have added

Comment: val df_file_feed =spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").option("host","1-1111").option("username","user").option("password","pasword").option("fileType","csv").load("/home/folder/Path_02.csv")
This is the data frame to read file from ftp

Comment: I tried all ways running from shell and also by doing spark-submit

Comment: Still facing the issue, Even after adding the packages. How did you overcome the issue @RamGhadiyaram

Comment: are you using maven or sbt if maven change the scope to runtime will add the jar in to uber jar

Comment: Anyone able to solve the issue? I am also facing same No class found error.